# Unexpected result from lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, lambda

I executed the following:

```
filter(lambda x: x%2 , range(10))
sum(filter(lambda x: x%2 , range(10)))
abc = filter(lambda x: x%2 , range(10))

sum(abc)    # => 25
sum(abc)    # => 0
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using Python 3.x. In Python 3.x, `filter` returns an iterable, not a list.

So, once you iterate the `filter` with the `sum` the first time, the `filter` iterable is exhausted. Next time, when you do the same, `filter` is already exhausted (it has no more elements). That is why you are getting the default return value 0.

You can confirm the same, like this

```
>>> abc = filter(lambda x: x%2 , range(10))
>>> list(abc)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> list(abc)
[]
```

Comment: Yes, I used Python 3.x. Thanks for the clarification!